# Why does nested virtualization seems disabled once an instance is stop and started after sometime?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kvm, virsh

I've setup nested virtualization on a virtual machine and could successfully run Windows guest on it. I used the google example which uses Debian from [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances)

The problem is once I shut down the instance and come later to try it does seem like nested virtualization is disabled. I am testing the following command:

```
grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo
```

Which normally returns a non-zero value when nested virtualization is enabled, but now returns zero.

Could it be a problem with nested virtualisation ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this simply by stopping and restarting the instance.

Comment: I reproduced it as well, I have misread your question before and provided an answer not completely related.

Comment: What could be the problem? I asked Google guys from their support and they say that one needs to ensure that they are using Haswell or later cpu and be in a region that supports haswell or later plus check that the used the correct license (I dont know how to verify the license once I use it in creating an image). I tried even using Skylake cpu but the instance doesnt start with nested virtualization enabled. There could be something wrong with the instances

Comment: I believe it is a bug, I updated the answer, it should not be anyhow related to your configuration.  @Michael

Answer (score 3):

> UPDATE: the bug has been solved.

I tested the behaviour and it is quite weird:

- if you reboot the instance it is not a problem, the nested virtualisation keeps working.
- if you stop the instance and restart it the nested virtualisation is no longer working and `grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo` return `0` as you noticed since.

Since I believe it is not the expected behaviour and it is a bug I raised an public bug in the google issuetracker, you can follow the updated and get updates through the following link:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/74331427

I advise you to star the public issue in order to get mail notifications.

**Disclaimer**: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support.